# Java/LWJGL 3 Optimization and Render error

Tags: java, opengl, optimization, render, lwjgl

I was following ThinMatrix's tutorial on OPENGL/LWJGL 3 3D Game Tutorial series [(here)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP), even though my code was wrote a little different from his, it was going well.

I could render an object like the image below using basic LWJGL 3 methods for rendering/shading. Basically, using this method in the **Render** class:

```
 //Old method
    
    public void createModel(EntityLoader entity, StaticShader shader) {
        
        ModelLoader model = entity.getModel();
        MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        shader.setUniformFloat("shineDamper", model.getShineDamper());
        shader.setUniformFloat("reflectivity", model.getReflectivity());
        
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransfMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), 
                entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.setUniformMatrix("transformationMatrix", transformationMatrix);
        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), "texture"), 0); 

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        
        mesh.cleanUp();
    }
```

And calling it out in the **main** class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Render render = new Render();
        window = render.init();
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        
        createCapabilities(); 
        Light light = new Light(new Vector3f(0,0,20), new Vector3f(1,1,1));
        
        ObjLoader obj = new ObjLoader();
        ModelLoader squareModel = obj.loadObj("game_engine/src/Objetos/Ico.obj");
        EntityLoader squareEntity = new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,0,-5),0,0,0,1);
        
        squareModel.setShineDamper(10);
        squareModel.setReflectivity(1);
        squareModel.loadTexture("game_engine/src/Texturas/awesomeface.png");
        
        Camera camera = new Camera();
        
        StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
        shader.start();
        shader.use();
        
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            render.prepare();
            processInput(window);
            
            glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, resizeWindow);
            GLFW.glfwSetScrollCallback(window, new GLFWScrollCallback() {
                @Override public void invoke (long win, double dx, double dy) {
                    XScroll = (float) dx;
                    YScroll = (float) dy;
                }
            });
            
            camera.move(window, YScroll);
            YScroll = 0;
            
            shader.setUniformVector("lightPosition", light.getPosition());
            shader.setUniformVector("lightColour", light.getColour());
        
            Matrix4f viewMatrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
            shader.setUniformMatrix("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);
        
            shader.setUniformMatrix("projectionMatrix", render.getProjectionMatrix());
            
            render.createModel(squareEntity, shader);
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();    
        }
        shader.cleanup();
        glfwTerminate();

    }
```

[image]

Until the 13 video, Optimizing, where he teached how to do the same procedure in a more optimized way, using HashMaps and ArrayLists to store the entities and calling the VAO elements only once per list of entities.
So, I made this **MasterRender** class:

```
public class Master {
    
    private StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
    private Render renderer = new Render(shader);
    
    private Map<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>> entities = new HashMap<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>>();
    
    public void render(Light sun, Camera camera){
        renderer.prepare();
        shader.start();
        shader.use();
        
        shader.setUniformVector("lightPosition", sun.getPosition());
        shader.setUniformVector("lightColour", sun.getColour());
        
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
        shader.setUniformMatrix("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);
        
        shader.setUniformMatrix("projectionMatrix", renderer.getProjectionMatrix());
    }
    
    public void processEntity(EntityLoader entity) {
        ModelLoader entityModel = entity.getModel();
        List<EntityLoader> batch = entities.get(entityModel);
        if(batch!=null) {
            batch.add(entity);
        }else {
            List<EntityLoader> newBatch = new ArrayList<EntityLoader>();
            newBatch.add(entity);
            entities.put(entityModel, newBatch);
        }
    }
    
    public void renderEntity() {
        
        renderer.render(entities);
        
        shader.stop();
        entities.clear();
    }
    
    public long loadWindow() {
        return renderer.init();
    }
    
    public void cleanup() {
        shader.cleanup();
    }

}
```

And used new methods in the Render class:

```
//Optimized methods
    
    public void render(Map<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>> entities) {
        for(ModelLoader model:entities.keySet()) {
            prepareModel(model);
            List<EntityLoader> batch = entities.get(model);
            for(EntityLoader entity : batch) {
                prepareEntity(entity);
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.createModel().getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            }
            unbindModel();
        }
        
    }
    
    private void prepareModel(ModelLoader model) {
        MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        shader.setUniformFloat("shineDamper", model.getShineDamper());
        shader.setUniformFloat("reflectivity", model.getReflectivity());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), "texture"), 0); 
        
    }
    
    private void unbindModel() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    }
    
    private void prepareEntity(EntityLoader entity) {
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransfMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), 
                entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.setUniformMatrix("transformationMatrix", transformationMatrix);
        
    }
```

Finally, I adjusted the **main** class, much like he did in the video

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Master render = new Master();
        window = render.loadWindow();
...
List<EntityLoader> allIcos = new ArrayList<EntityLoader>();
        allIcos.add(new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,0,-5),0,0,0,1));
        
        while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            processInput(window);
            
            glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, resizeWindow);
            GLFW.glfwSetScrollCallback(window, new GLFWScrollCallback() {
                @Override public void invoke (long win, double dx, double dy) {
                    XScroll = (float) dx;
                    YScroll = (float) dy;
                }
            });
            
            camera.move(window, YScroll);
            YScroll = 0;

            render.render(light, camera);
            for(EntityLoader Ico : allIcos) {
                render.processEntity(Ico);
                Ico.changeRot(0, 3, 0);
            }
            render.renderEntity();
            
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();    
        }
```

Not only it didn't work, it bought up a log error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8b8cd07b0, pid=11800, tid=7260
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (16.0.2+7) (build 16.0.2+7-67)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.dll+0x8507b0]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages br.com.renanlima.git.main

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001ae5e0ce780):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7260, stack(0x0000007d29000000,0x0000007d29100000)]

Stack: [0x0000007d29000000,0x0000007d29100000],  sp=0x0000007d290ff350,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglv64.dll+0x8507b0]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.nglDrawElements(IIIJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  br.com.renanlima.render.Render.render(Ljava/util/Map;)V+84
j  br.com.renanlima.render.Master.renderEntity()V+8
j  br.com.renanlima.git.main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+254
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000
...
```

My question is:What did I do wrong in this new method of rendering? I looked up other tutorials besides ThinMatrix's one and they seen to all do it in a similar way.

**EDIT 1:** So, using Eclipse's debugger I found out 2 things:
1 - For some reason, the "transformationMatrix" is loading different, even though the two methods are the same and the parameters they are getting are the same.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3n0q.png) are the matrix variables using the "createModel()" method, the one that works

[And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOkeq.png) are the matrix variables using the optimized method, the one that doesn't work

This seems to be the only matrix/vertex in which this happens, but I could be overlooking something

2 - I think I've pinpointed the specific part where the crash happens.
When running the "glDrawElements" method.

[image]

More especificaly, on this part of the method:

[image]

But none of the variables seem to be wrong before that method is called. Again, I could be overlooking something, but there are a sh*tton of variables at the "findNative()" part, so I will look better into it.

**EDIT 1.2:** I solved the transformationMatrix error. It was because of the "changeRot(0, 3, 0);" being called early. But I still can't find out why the crash at "glDrawElements" happens. Can someone please help me with this? If the question is confusing, please tell me so I can try to explain it better.

Comment: glDrawElements takes the number of indices, not vertices.  Does changing `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.createModel().getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);` from vertex count to index count fix your problem?

Comment: The "getVertexCount()" method actually pulls the indice count, it's just a naming problem. And in the "createModel()", the one that works, uses this method as well.

Comment: Just to sanity check, there is a element array buffer associated with the vao?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after dealing with college and work stuff, I finally returned to this code, and I could at last fix my mistakes. Shoutouts to Nick Clark for it's comment on the buffers associated with the VAO.

The problem seems to happen because of this line of code

```
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.createModel().getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Specifically on the "model.createModel()" part. It creates another clean mesh, with no buffers associated with it's VAO. The old method worked because I called the "vertex count" (which is actually the index count, and I named it wrong) directly from an mesh object, as in:

```
MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
...
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

So, to fix the error, I kind of merged the two methods into a new one:

```
//Optimized method

public void render(Map<ModelLoader, List<EntityLoader>> entities) {
    for(ModelLoader model:entities.keySet()) {
        MeshLoader mesh = model.createModel();
        glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVaoId());
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        shader.setUniformFloat("shineDamper", model.getShineDamper());
        shader.setUniformFloat("reflectivity", model.getReflectivity());
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture());
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getID(), "texture"), 0); 
        List<EntityLoader> batch = entities.get(model);
        for(EntityLoader entity : batch) {
            prepareEntity(entity);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        }
        mesh.cleanUp();
    }
    
}
```

And now I can render objects in a *theoretically* optimized way

```
//main class
List<EntityLoader> allIcos = new ArrayList<EntityLoader>();
    allIcos.add(new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,0,-5),0,0,0,1));
    allIcos.add(new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,5,-5),0,0,0,1));
    allIcos.add(new EntityLoader(squareModel, new Vector3f(0,-5,-5),0,0,0,1));
...
render.render(light, camera);
        for(EntityLoader Ico : allIcos) {
            render.processEntity(Ico);
        }
        render.renderEntity();
```

[image]

I'll try to optimize and clean this code, but for now that's how it's going to work.
Feel free to correct any naming/terminology mistakes in this answer, it's mostly because of my bad grasp of both english and Java lingo.